# PushSharp 4.0 - Namespace not recognized "PushBroker"

Tags: ios, namespace, apple-push-notification

Estou com o seguinte problema, recentemente adicionei ao meu servidor a lib `PushSharp` 4.0 para poder enviar notificações para ios.

No entanto com o código que tenho, estou a ter o seguinte erro:

> the type namespace name 'PushBroker' could not be found

O código que tenho é o seguinte:

```
using PushSharp;
using PushSharp.Core;
using PushSharp.Apple;

var push = new PushBroker();

try
{
   var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(test);//Server.MapPath(test));

   push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(true, appleCert, _iphoneCertPasswordV2));

   push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                .ForDeviceToken(device)//the recipient device id
                .WithAlert("Mensagem a enviar")//the message
                .WithBadge(1)
                .WithSound("sound.caf")
   );
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Porque razão é que não reconhece o `PushBroker`? O mesmo acontece mais em baixo com `AppleNotification()`.

Comment: @Taisbevalle erros de poucas linhas não é necessário formatar como código e citação juntos.

Comment: Obrigada pela informação, @diegofm